# What are perms in terms of IBM Doors?

Tags: ibm-doors, perms

Hi in the Internet I see:

This function is hidden and can be used like perm or use that perm for that?

So what are perms? Hidden developers functions or private functions which are not suppose to be used by users only for internal use? Why there is no documentation for them? I saw excel sheet with over 7700 perms which  are not documented but can be used? Can you give me more information about them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**perms** are the built-in-"functions/procedures" that the DXL interpreter provides in the DOORS binary. They're not "hidden" and they are listed in the DXL specification. The ones you've probably come across were the undocumented perms, which there are plenty of, as you've discovered.  Although, there is no guarantee of stability with the undocumented procedures, so take caution.